# Custom types not found in Postgresql with psycopg2

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

**Introduction:**

I'm trying to insert data with Python/psycopg2 into Postgres in the following format:

```
(integer, date, integer, customtype[], customtype[], customtype[], customtype[])
```

However, as I try to insert them, I always get this error:

> '"customtype[]" does not exist'

---

**How is my setup:**

I have a dict with the data I need, like so:

```
data_dict = {'integer1':1, 'date': datetime(), 
             'integer2': 2, 'custom1':[(str, double, double),(str, double, double)], 
             'custom2':[(str, double, double),(str, double, double),(str, double, double)],
             'custom3':[(str, double, double),(str, double, double),(str, double, double)],
             'custom4':[(str, double, double)]}
```

Each custom array can have as many custom tuples as needed.

I've already created a type for these custom tuples, as such:

```
"CREATE TYPE customtype AS (text, double precision, double precision)"
```

And I've created a table with columns of customtype[].

---

**What I've tried so far:**

```
query = """INSERT INTO table (column names...) VALUES
            (%(integer1)s, %(date)s, %(integer2)s, 
            %(custom1)s::customtype[], [...]);"""
```

And:

```
query = """INSERT INTO table (column names...) VALUES
            (%(integer1)s, %(date)s, %(integer2)s, 
            CAST(%(custom1)s AS customtype[]), [...]);"""
```

But both options render the same results.

*The final question:*

**How to insert these record-type arrays in Postgresql with Psycopg2?**

Maybe I'm probably misunderstanding completely how Postgresql works. I'm comming from a BigQuery Record/Repeated type background.

Ps.: This is how I'm querying:

```
cursor.execute(query,data_dict)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I created the type inside the Database.

When referencing custom types in Postgresql, there's a need to reference the database where the type was created as well as the type.

Like so:

```
(%(dict_name)s)::"database_name".type
#or
CAST(%(dict_name)s as "database_name".type)
```

Be carefull with the quoting!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of an old question and it set me on the right track to finding the answer but didn't quite get me all the way.

I had a function which needed to return a custom type. I needed to attach public before the custom type.

```
RETURNS TABLE (
    "status" "public"."my_custom_status_type",
    "ID" VARCHAR(255)
    )
```

So directly answering OP's question, try adding public before the type.

```
query = """INSERT INTO table (column names...) VALUES
            (%(integer1)s, %(date)s, %(integer2)s, 
            CAST(%(custom1)s AS public.customtype[]), [...]);"""
```